# Build openssl without debugging strings / symbols

Tags: cmake, openssl

I used vcpkg to install openssl for tripplet: `openssl:x64-mingw-static 3.1.1#1`

And i found many debugging symbols, i used release version, not debug

how can i configure vcpkg to build openssl without those debugging symbols
[image]

[image]